# Visa needed for a seminar in London

Tags: visas, uk, afghan-citizens

I am from Afghanistan and got a partial scholarship from UNICAF for studying MBA online program at South Wales University UK. UNICAF is offering me to attend a seminar in the UK capital, meet and network with faculty members.
I don't know what type of visa I need to apply, and where to apply.

Answer (score 10):

On the following Portal

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

You can provide some basic details about your visit and will be informed that you can apply for:

> **Standard Visitor visa** 
>   - eg if you’re coming to the UK for conferences, meetings, training, academic research or a sabbatical

You'd need to **[apply online](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply)** and then appear for Biometrics and to submit supporting documents at a **[VAC](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/global/index.html)** (Visa Application Centre) in Pakistan or India.